# Expectation related to geometric random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a Geometric random variable (with parameter $p$ and range $\{k\geq 1\}$).

Let $M$ be a positive integer.

Let $Z:=\min\{X,M\}$. We want to calculate the expectation $\mathbb E[Z]$.

---

My professor solved the problem by starting with $$\mathbb E[Z]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P[Z\geq k].$$

I can understand all other steps in his method except this starting step. Why shouldn't we have $\mathbb E[Z]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P[Z= k]$ by the definition of expectation instead?

I am really confused by this starting step. Any help with understanding the step $\mathbb E[Z]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P[Z\geq k]$ will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation holds for nonnegative random variable.

\begin{align}
E[Z]&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP[Z=k]\\
&=P(Z=1)\\
&+P(Z=2) + P(Z=2)\\
&+P(Z=3) + P(Z=3) + P(Z=3)+\ldots\\
\vdots\\
&=P(Z\ge 1) + P(Z\ge 2)+P(Z\ge 3)+\ldots\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(Z \ge k)
\end{align}

where the third equation is due to we sum the terms columnwise.

Answer (score 2):

They are actually equal:
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P[Z= k] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P[Z\geq k] $

Consider this sum:

$
+ \; P(1)  \\
+P(2) + P(2) \\
+P(3) + P(3) + P(3) \\
\vdots
$

The rowwise grouping of  this sum  is the LHS, while the columnwise grouping is the RHS.